# Why can't I keep my articles published recently when I redeploy my flask app on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-toolbelt

I write a simple script `publish.py` for publishing articles written in markdown.
so i can use:

```
python3 publish.py -a https://MYNAME.herokuapp.com/publish -p article.md -t MYTOKEN
```

to upload my article and save it in my `sqlite database test.db`

my route function:

```
@main.route('/publish', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def publish():
  if request.method == 'GET':
      abort(404)

  # authorization
  token = request.form.get('token', '')
  if token != current_app.config['TOKEN']:
      return 'invalid access token', 500

  title = request.form.get('title', None)
  if not title:
      return 'no title found', 500

  summary = request.form.get('summary', None)
  if not summary:
      return 'no summary found', 500

  content = request.form.get('content', None)
  if not content:
      return 'no content found', 500

  content = markdown2html(content)
  pub_time = request.form.get('pub_time', None)
  if pub_time:
      pub_time = datetime.strptime(pub_time, app.config['TIME_FORMAT'])

  tags = request.form.getlist('tags')

  create_article(title, summary, content, pub_time, tags)
  return '', 200
```

when I publish an artilce by the script it sames normal, my website can show this article. 
but when i `push new changes` on Heroku and restart it, my article published just now disppeared!

```
heroku maintenance:on
git push heroku master
heroku run python3 manage.py db upgrade
heroku restart
heroku maintenance:off
```

How can i keep my old articles when i have to push new changes on Heroku.
(and it's quite normal if i run my server on my localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, `create_article` writes the post to a file or to a SQLite database? Heroku [does not keep data you store on disk](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), so you cannot use these ways of storing data.

Instead, use a Postgres database. Heroku [provides you one](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite database needs files to keep data. `create_article` updates the database, whose files are stored in some [dyno](https://www.heroku.com/dynos). This means that you can post new articles as long as you do not perform dyno-related operations like deploying (pushing to the remote branch) or restarting.

To avoid this situation you might want to store the database files somewhere else, but running [other databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/data-management) is a better approach.

More info about dynos: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos